# C++14: Initializing constexpr variables from parameter values

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, constexpr

Say I have a class that that can return a constant expression through a `constexpr` function:

```
template<int N>
struct Foo {
  constexpr int Bar() const { return N; }
};
```

If I wanted to initialize constexpr values from `Foo::Bar()`, how should I pass a parameter of type `Foo`? I've tried these two, with an example `constexpr` variable inside of each to test that it can be initialized:

```
template<int N>
constexpr int ByValue(Foo<N> f) {
  constexpr int i = f.Bar();
  return f.Bar();
}

template<int N>
constexpr int ByReference(const Foo<N> &f) {
  constexpr int i = f.Bar();
  return f.Bar();
}

constexpr int a = ByValue(Foo<1>{});
constexpr int b = ByReference(Foo<1>{});
```

But clang 3.7 raises an error on `ByReference` while gcc >=5.1 does not: [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/583cf2c333edcb83)

```
main.cpp:15:25: error: constexpr variable 'i' must be initialized by a constant expression
      constexpr int i = f.Bar();
                        ^~~~~~~
main.cpp:22:25: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'ByReference<1>' requested here
      constexpr int b = ByReference(Foo<1>{});
```

What's the difference between taking a `const Foo &` or a plain `Foo`, when `Bar` is `constexpr` either way and returns a valid constant expression?

Which is right and why, GCC or Clang? If available, references to the standard would be appreciated.

Comment: There is some silly language about references in the standard's enumeration of what can give you a compile time constant expression. Evidently clang pedantically honors that language, while g++ more practically disregards it. Hopefully it will be fixed, but I can't recall seeing any defect report about it. Upshot: this is gray zone, and may continue to be one. Use macros to define general array size function, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: You need to make your member function `static`, so that it doesn't depend on an implicit `this` pointer and maybe disqualify itself from being a constant expression.

Comment: I don't have the time to give an answer now but this is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31375381/1708801)

Comment: I added a section about the array size problem to [the FAQ on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c/7439261#7439261), now 5.4. Note to @Columbo, due to his argumentation here (now removed): this section of the FAQ was originally written by me. You can learn all about the dangers of this and that. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

§5.20:

[image]

The reference does not have a preceding initialization from the point of view of `i`, though: It's a parameter. It's initialized once `ByReference` is called.

Let's remove the `constexpr` from `i`'s declaration and consider an invocation of `ByReference` in its entirety:

```
template<int N>
constexpr int ByReference(const Foo<N> &f) {
    int i = f.Bar();
    return i;
}

constexpr int j = ByReference(Foo<0>());
```

This is fine, since `f` does have preceding initialization. The initializer of `f` is a constant expression as well, since the implicitly declared default constructor is `constexpr` in this case (§12.1/5).
Hence `i` is initialized by a constant expression and the invocation is a constant expression itself.

Comment: @Walter No. Clang rejects it, thus it's right. By the current rules, that is.

Comment: I am a fan of this screenshot / highlight approach to quoting. +1!

Comment: @Barry Yeah, I figured this would be more comprehensible than my attempts of creating tables in markdown ;-)

Comment: @Columbo What's the difference between your example and OP's with regards to "preceding initialization"? They look the same to me as far as `f` is concerned.

Comment: If `i` inside the function is marked as `constexpr`, then the initializer must be a constant expression *itself*. But it isn't, because the reference used has not been initialized at that point. However, `ByReference(Foo<0>())` is a constant expression because the parameter has indeed been initialized when `i` is about to be initialized. A similar case is shown in the example section of §5.20/2 with `incr`.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Simply quote the text back in here.

Comment: @ʎǝɹɟɟɟǝſ …and why exactly wouldn't I post pictures of text when I could never reach the nice formatting that the picture shows with markdown?

Comment: @Columbo Because blind people also visit the website.

Comment: "because the reference used has not been initialized at that point", what do you mean by "at that point"? Do you mean a time point when the program is executing, or a lexical point of the program? If you mean the former, the reference is indeed initialized at that point. If you mean the latter, why is that different for `ByReference(Foo<0>())` (while the lexical structure of the program is the same)?

Comment: @xskxzr Another way to see it is that you can't have a constexpr reference refer to different objects. In this case, because the reference is a parameter, it can be called with different objects

Comment: @Rakete1111 I know the rationality of the rule: when the compiler parses `int i = f.Bar();`, it does not know what `f` refers to, when the compiler parses  `constexpr int j = ByReference(Foo<0>());`, it knows what `f` refers to. I'm just confused with the unclear wording "preceding" in the specification.

Comment: @xskxzr Ahh great. Yeah, I find it a bit weird too.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I have filed an [editorial issue](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2307), and someone pointed out that this is already a [core language issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2186).