# calling a template parameter constexpr method?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, constexpr

`std::array<...>::size()` is a non-`static` `constexpr` method; being `constexpr` I can use it as a template parameter:

```
#include <array>
#include <stdio>

int main(void) {
  std::array<char, 12> a = {{ "Hello world" }};
  std::cout << "size() = " << a.size() << ", data() = \"" << a.data() << "\"" << std::endl;

  std::array<char, a.size()> b = a;
  std::cout << "size() = " << b.size() << ", data() = \"" << b.data() << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

However, if the `std::array<...>` is a template parameter, things become uncertain:

```
template <typename T>
void copy(T const& a) {
  std::array<char, a.size()> c = a;
  std::cout << "size() = " << c.size() << ", data() = \"" << c.data() << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

GCC happily compiles this [1], while CLANG refuses [2] with

```
<source>:6:20: error: non-type template argument is not a constant expression
  std::array<char, a.size()> c = a;
```

[1] https://godbolt.org/z/Ru7Y3F
[2] https://godbolt.org/z/LYJcpo

Which one is correct, according to the standard ?

---

P.S.
Yes, I know that I can work around it using `std::tuple_size`:

```
template <typename T>
void copy(T const& a) {
  std::array<char, std::tuple_size<T>::value> c = a;
  std::cout << "size() = " << c.size() << ", data() = \"" << c.data() << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Clang seems to be buggy.

Answer (score 3):

Clang is correct.

You are evaluating an id-expression (`a`) of reference type that does not has a preceding initialization, which is not allowed in a constant expression.

[[expr.const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2):

> An expression `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - ...
> - an *id-expression* that refers to a variable or data member of reference type unless the reference has a preceding initialization and either
>
>   - it is initialized with a constant expression or
>   - its lifetime began within the evaluation of `e`;
> - ...

Comment: What's a preceding initialization? `a` does get initialized?

Comment: Isn't every reference initialized? In syntax? How else would I initialize a reference?

Comment: @Rakete1111 Sorry I didn't get your point. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720324/5376789) may help.

Comment: That answer helped a lot! Thanks! So to anyone: When the function is instantiated, `a` doesn't have an initializer (yet).

Comment: @Rakete1111 After reading that answer carefully, I'm also confused with the word "preceding". I'll reply to you if I figure it out.

Comment: Me too, until I read this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714790/c14-initializing-constexpr-variables-from-parameter-values/31720324#comment51384687_31720324

Comment: Isn't the linked post a dupe?

Comment: @PasserBy I don't know. The question looks not that similar though the answer may be the same.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I have replied to that comment about my confusion.