# Reasonable hash for pairs in non performance-critical situations

Tags: c++, hash

I have situations where I have a `unordered_map<std::pair<T, U>>` where the container won't be big (two or three hundred entries at most?) and the queries won't be specially frequent (hundreds per second at most?)

That's not too much, but I don't wan't to do anything stupid either. Is it "reasonable" to have a hash function like?

```
class my_hasher
{
    std::size_t operator()(auto const& k) const noexcept
    {
       std::hash<T> hT;
       std::hash<U> hU;
       return hT(k.first) ^ hT(k.second); 
    }
};
```

under the assumption that hT and hU are good hash-functions. For example, what about for  `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`? (what about `std::pair<int, int>` where the default hash function is the identity?)

What is a reasonable way of combining hash functions for non performance-critical situations?

I could of course "copy" `boost::hash_combine` and do something like

```
std::size_t ret = hT(k.first); 
return ret ^ hU(k.second) + 0x9e3779b9 + (ret << 6) + (ret >> 2);
```

but I don't want to overdo simple things with bit-tricks unless it's really neccesary, but I don't want to create stupid hash functions either.

Comment: The problem with your hash is that it will always produce collision if first == second (e.g. when T and U are the same). Of course with three hundred entries it is unlikely to matter. On the other hand just copy the formula. Its not like it soo long and complicated that it is worth spending time on.

Comment: If you want performance, I'd use a different hash map.  `std::unordered_map` is basically required to be implemented as a `std::vector<std::list<Value>>`  which is not a cache friendly data structure.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588384/4342498

Comment: Do you need to support any type, or are you primarily expecting pairs of strings and pairs of ints?

Comment: @Urausgeruhtkin I rarely have situations outside numbers or std::string, so yes, primarily expecting pairs of strings and ints/unsigneds.

Comment: @freakish yes good point, I haven't though about pairs of equal members. That's what I meant about avoiding stupid hash functions...

Answer (score 1):

If your integers are small enough such that `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits + std::numeric_limits<U>::digits < std::numeric_limits<long long>::digits`, they can be combined into a larger integer before hashing with `std::hash`.  This is similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39690912), though instead of shifting by a hard-coded value, it could be done as:

EDIT: version that makes full use of all available bits:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<typename Int_Type>
struct integer_storage_bits 
: public std::integral_constant<
    unsigned, 
    std::numeric_limits<Int_Type>::digits 
    + static_cast<unsigned>(std::numeric_limits<Int_Type>::is_signed)
>
{
     static_assert(
          std::numeric_limits<Int_Type>::is_specialized 
          & std::numeric_limits<Int_Type>::is_integer
          & (std::numeric_limits<Int_Type>::radix == 2),
         "assumption violation: only correct for base 2 integers"
     );
};


struct integral_pair_hasher
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    std::size_t operator()(std::pair<T,U> const & k) const noexcept
    {
         static_assert(
              integer_storage_bits<U>::value + integer_storage_bits<T>::value 
              <= integer_storage_bits<unsigned long long>::value,
              "bits don't fit"
         );

         static constexpr unsigned long long const mask = 
              (1ull << (integer_storage_bits<U>::value)) - 1u;

         return std::hash(
           (
              static_cast<unsigned long long>(k.first) 
              << integer_storage_bits<U>::value
           ) 
           | (static_cast<unsigned long long>(k.second) & mask)
         );
    }
};
```

Original implementation mentioned in comments:

```
std::size_t operator()(std::pair<T,U> k) const noexcept
{
   static_assert(std::numeric_limits<T>::digits + std::numeric_limits<U>::digits < std::numeric_limits<long long>::digits, "integer overflow possible in hash function");
   static constexpr long long mult = 1ll << std::numeric_limits<U>::digits;
   return std::hash(k.first * mult + k.second);
}
```

Strings are a little more work, but here are a couple options that might be reasonable.  Be aware that if you have cases where the separation of the pair is part of the uniqueness (for example, the pair "apple", "orange" and the pair "appleorange", ""), these might cause you problems:

1. Instead store a `std::pair<std::string, std::string::size_type>` as your key, and for hashing, just forward to `std::hash<std::string>`.  This string would be created by simply appending one string to the other, with the length of the first string stored as the second member of the pair, so that you can get the original strings "back" as `std::string_view` in constant time.  If `std::string_view` is too awkward for your use case, this isn't a great option, but does allow you to stick with `std::hash` without resorting to further trickery.
2. The FNV-1a hash [has a public domain C implementation](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/fnv/#FNV-reference-source) that works on character sequences.  Your hash functor could run the first string through fnv using the recommended offset, and run the second string through it using the result of the first string as the offset.  There are other established hash functions (which may be faster than FNV-1a), but in addition to the public domain reference implementation, a benefit of FNV-1a is that [it is possible to make it constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48896410), so if you find yourself with use-cases where you want to pre-calculate the hash of string literals at compile-time, it can be made to work for that, too.

Comment: `mult = 1ll << ...` and then `k.first * mult` makes me a bit nervous about signed integer overflows. Wouldn't `1ull` (or `size_t(1)`) be better?

Comment: One issue with `pair<string, size_t>` is that at least GCC's hash table tries to detect that it has string keys and then caches the hash value, which it doesn't do normally and also not for custom types. So in this case I recommend a custom struct that caches the hash value internally unless you don't care about repeated invocations of the string hash function

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo
That is why the is a static_assert uses "<" on the number of digits, though admittedly I should have also confirmed that numeric_limits is_specialized, is_integer, and has radix == 2.  1 << Y = 2^Y, so we have as worst-case inputs  -2^X*2^Y = -2^(X+Y), but we can store -2^Z, and we checked that X + Y < Z, so we can store at least -2^(X+Y+1) for the multiplication. Then we add worst case -2^Y, so now we have -2^(X+Y) + -2^Y, but since we can store -2^(X+Y+1) = -2^(X+Y)*2^1 = -2^(X+Y) + -2(X+Y), and even if X is somehow 0, -2^(X+Y) + -2^(X+Y) <= -2^X+Y) + -2^Y, so it still fits.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo though it is somewhat unsatisfying to get a compile error trying to fit two 32-bit unsigned integers into a 64-bit space just because that space is signed.  There's an updated implementation now.