Generating a unique id of string at compile-time
I want to generate a unique ID for a std::string which runs at a compile-time.
I've tried using std::hash, but it only works at runtime.
Here is an example code of what I'm trying to accomplish:
#define DECLARE_COMPONENT(T) \
static constexpr std::string GetObjectName() { return #T; } \
static size_t GetObjectId() { \
return std::hash\<std::string\>{}(#T);}

But the issue is that I want GetObjectId() to compute an ID at compile-time, and from what I know, std::hash is only evaluated at runtime.
What would be the most efficient and fastest way to achieve this? Any suggestions ?

Maybe a duplicate?

Which C++ standard? Note that std::string can't be result of constexpr https://stackoverflow.com/q/27123306/1387438

I think your problem is also caused by this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48896410/1387438

I would do something like this (without macros)
#include <string_view>

// some cooked up "hash" function that converts a string
// with a high probability to a unique value
static constexpr std::size_t id_from_string(std::string_view str) 
{
    std::size_t id{};
    for (char c : str) 
    {
        id = (id * 31) + static_cast<std::size_t>(c);
    }
    return id;
}

// rely on the fact that for each type
// this function will get a different __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ value
// (it doesn't really matter what that string is)
template<typename type_t>
static constexpr std::size_t id_from_type() 
{
    return id_from_string(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr std::size_t id = id_from_type<int>();
    constexpr std::size_t id2 = id_from_type<float>();
    constexpr std::size_t id3 = id_from_string("HelloWorld");
    return 0;
}

