# Checking the size of a user defined string litteral at compile time in C++11

Tags: string, c++11

I'm trying to restrict the use of some **user defined** litteral for string to a given length

```cpp
 Carte operator"" _C (const char* str, std::size_t sz) {
  if (sz != 2)
    throw runtime_error("Wrong size of string");
  return from_string(str);
}
```

This works perfectly except that since litteral is known at compile time, the size test could be done at that time as well. However the I can't use a static assert here

```
jeu.cpp:105:17: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
  static_assert(sz == 2, "Wrong size of string");
                ^~~~~~~
jeu.cpp:105:17: note: read of non-const variable 'sz' is not allowed in a constant expression
jeu.cpp:104:51: note: declared here
```

Is there a way to check the size of user defined string litteral at compile time in c++11 ?
If not, is it possible with more recent standard of c++ ?

Comment: can try this trick ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890784/computing-length-of-a-c-string-at-compile-time-is-this-really-a-constexpr

Comment: @KvaeKvae22 Same problem : "read of non-constexpr variable 'str' is not allowed in a constant expression". The compiler doesn't seems to see that str and sz are constants.

Answer (score -1):

use sizeof(test) to get length.. then you can use static_assert

```
const char test[] = "blablalba";
static_assert (sizeof(test) == 10);
```

Comment: This doesn't work inside the function which makes the user defined litteral. The sizeof is on the parameter str (IE : pointer to char and not the string litteral).