# Cast to `constexpr`

Tags: c++

Lets say I have:

*(please ignore the fact that I am using `strncmp` in C++)*

```cpp
if (!strncmp(some_str, "constant", strlen("constant"))) {}
```

The `strlen` can be evaluated at compile time but it can't be eliminated because the function is not `constexpr`.

One way around would be (accepted only by `g++`):

```cpp
constexpr size_t len = strlen("constant");
if (!strncmp(some_str, "constant", len)) {}
```

but this is harder to read and less practical.

Is there any way to specify `constexpr` for a part of a statement?

Comment: Cppreference says `std::strlen()` is not `constexpr`. What do you mean by "can't be eliminated"?

Comment: Exactly, the compiler will insert a runtime call - because it does know that this could potentially be a `constexpr`

Comment: I expect a sane compiler to optimize away the call. Because it's not constexpr, `constexpr size_t len = strlen(...);` won't compile, though.

Comment: In a case like this, a `std::string_view` literal would have been more expressive in every way imaginable.

Comment: `constexpr size_t len = strlen("constant");` is valid C++

Comment: @mmomtchev [It is not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c04dc5400dd84e2a)

Comment: [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) is not `constexpr`

Comment: anyhow if it was `constexpr` the compiler would know that and I dont understand why you expect the two versions of the code to be better or worse concerning what the compiler can / will do at compile time

Comment: `g++` does accept it

Comment: @mmomtchev It does, but it shouldn't.  It is a non-standard extension.

Comment: `strlen("constant")` is obviously an expression that can be evaluated compile time - the question was therefore if it was possible to signal this to the compiler

Comment: As a courtesy by an optimizing compiler - yes. But in standard C++ - no.

Comment: The compiler has to be aware that `strlen` does not have any side-effects

Comment: GCC optimizes it away here: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9MYr4ra5c

Comment: @HolyBlackCat @NathanOliver this means that `g++` knows that `strlen` does not have any side-effects and surely explains why it accepts it in a `constexpr` - it is probably something specific to `g++`

Comment: That's what Nathan Oliver meant when he said it's a non-standard extension. GCC is allowed to optimize it away, but it's not allowed to accept it as an initializer for a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: The answer is that `strlen` is a compiler intrinsic and this is the reason that it can be optimized away - and this applies to both `g++` and `clang`.

Comment: @mmomtchev: But it's still not valid *standard* C++. It's just a thing certain compilers may do. It is unreliable; it may work today and fail tomorrow.

Comment: @mmomtchev: If you want a `constexpr` string length computation, you can use `std::char_traits<char>::length`, which in C++17 is `constexpr`. But if you can use C++17, you really ought to just use `string_view`.

Answer (score 1):

This is fundamentally impossible. Compilers can delay evaluation - do `constexpr` calculations later, at runtime. But they can't travel back in time. If even a single (evaluated) subexpression is not `constexpr`, then the whole expression cannot be `constexpr`.

Comment: In this particular case, everything can be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @mmomtchev then if compiler is sophisticated enough, it will evaluate everything in compile time. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5nTbTn853

Comment: @mmomtchev and if it isn't, then your "hint" will just cause it to fail with an error. __Because it isn't sophisticated enough to calculate that in compile time.__

Comment: @mmomtchev: `constexpr` is a bit stronger: **every** C++ compiler must be able to do the evaluation at compile time. And as noted, the Standard does not require that compilers make `strlen` `constexpr`. A compliant compiler can have `strlen` just in its runtime library, which is too late to initialize `constexpr` variables such as `len` in your examples.

Comment: The question is discussed at length here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890784/computing-length-of-a-c-string-at-compile-time-is-this-really-a-constexpr

Comment: @mmomtchev: Well, that's not `strlen`. That,s a user-defined `length()` function which is literally defined as `constexpr`, unlike `strlen` (since C++ inherits it from C, and C doesn't have `constexpr`, and C++ didn't add it when inheriting)

Comment: All the questions asked here have been discussed at great length in the answers and comments - including the fact that `strlen` is a compiler intrinsic and not a runtime library function

Comment: @mmomtchev: What certain compilers do is not the question. What compilers *have to do* is the question. Compilers can do all kinds of non-standard things; that doesn't make it "C++".

Comment: The original question was if there was any way to specify that an expression should be evaluated at compile time when the function is not `constexpr` - and it seems that the answer might be no - but no one has really answered that

Comment: @mmomtchev: Your original question talks about applying `constexpr` to part of a statement. Indeed, it doesn't even recognize that `strlen` is *not* `constexpr`, since it says the exact opposite. So if that is what you want to know, maybe you should change your question to ask that.

Comment: I did change it.

Comment: @mmomtchev: Compilers **must** have `strlen` as a runtime function, because you can write `&strlen`. Optimizers may add an intrinsic version, but this is strictly optional

Answer (score 1):

You have to be in specific case to force `constexpr` evaluation, `std::integral_constant` might help:

```
if (!strncmp(some_str,
             "constant",
             std::integral_constant<std::size_t, strlen("constant")>()))
{
// ...
}
```

alias/MACRO might shorten `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, strlen("constant")>()`

Not sure it is better than your:

```
constexpr size_t len = strlen("constant");
if (!strncmp(some_str, "constant", len))
{
    // ...
}
```

Note: I assume that `strlen` is your own `constexpr` version (as standard one is not `constexpr`).

Comment: This still doesn't work in `clang`: `non-constexpr function 'strlen' cannot be used in a constant expression`

Comment: @mmomtchev: That's because `strlen` is not a `constexpr` function. If a function is not declared as `constexpr`, it cannot appear in a constant expression. Since that's what `constexpr` *means*.

Comment: @mmomtchev: Seems you miss my last note. Your work around would also fail with non-`constexpr` `strlen`.

Comment: I updated my question, which is in fact, is there any way to ask the compiler to evaluate an expression at compile time without the functions used being marked as `constexpr`

Comment: You cannot enforce compile time evaluation of non-constexpr functions. As-if rule allows the compiler to optimize (aggressively) though (but result cannot be stored in constexpr variable anyway).